# Where can I find xuggler simple tutorials?

Tags: java, xuggler

I'm making a simple messaging application for a webpage in my country. I tried to learn JMF but in my opinion it's too old and I just don't want to use it. I searched stackoverflow and it seems that xuggler is a better way to manage media. can someone give me a link to a free ebook or something to start from?

thank you

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for guidance. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. [first](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-transcoding-media.html)
2. [second](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html)
3. [third(in russian)](http://programador.ru/video-audio-xuggle/)

Comment: thank you ill check them today. +1 for the first and second. for the third XD.